# When serializing a Java object is it possible to capture the byte offsets for the objects fields and methods?

Tags: java, serialization, bytebuffer

I'm interested in doing this because i'd like to write Java objects to DirectByteBuffers, and then later access and manipulate the object in a fast way, without having to de-serialize. The idea is to avoid creating objects on the GC managed heap, instead create objects in non-heap DirectByteBuffers and then have a safe way of manipulating these objects.

Comment: You can implement `readObject` and `writeObject` to manually handle object serialization / deserialization.

Comment: I didn't know java serialization captured methods.

Comment: Duplicate of your [What is the safest way to use direct byte buffers in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446266/what-is-the-safest-way-to-use-direct-byte-buffers-in-java)

Comment: @JasonSperske It doesn't, but methods aren't mentioned in the question. Your point?

Comment: I was just responding to the "fields and methods" part of the question title, but it looks like this question is well addressed by people who know a lot more about this than I do. I don't think I have any meaningful insight to add.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to capture offsets using the Unsafe class. However You won't be able to get a valid ObjectPointer into your byteBuffer, so you might be able to create (theoretically) accessible Objects in a bytebuffer, but you won't be able to actually manipulate them.

A way to go is to generate byte-code at runtime and create kind of "pointer"-wrapper classes which access the byte buffer when getters/setters are called.

an example of something like this (but uses byte arrays instead of bytebuffer)
can be found here

http://code.google.com/p/fast-serialization/wiki/StructsIntroduction

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you really want, see Object Serialization Stream Protocol  here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you need to do all the work yourself or use a library which does this for you. Javolution Structs supports mapping of off heap memory as a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this sort of solution, its a bit of a work around...

```
 interface OffsetMemberMap {
     Map<String,Long> offsetMemberMap();
}
```

The idea is to create objects that implement the above interface, this map will store memory addresses against Strings for each member. Child objects would be created first and once added to a DirectByteBuffer the offset position would be stored in the parent within this map.
In order to access a specific member the user would need to supply the string which addresses that member and thus only what's needed would be de-serialized. This would allow you to store large linked objects in DirectByteBuffers whilst being able to only serialize/de-serialize the bits you need when writing/reading.

So if you had a School class, with HeadTeacher member and the HeadTeacher had a Details member, you could access the details instance from the DirectByteBuffer using a string like school.headteacher.details

ie. So long as you have the parent Object address you can get parent Object from the byte buffer and thus continue to get the specified child Object.